# org.joda.time.DateTime.parse in Netbans okay but in eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jodatime

I'm very confused right now

The following line is compiled in NetBeans but not in eclipse (same PC, same JAVA-Version, both import org.joda.time.DateTime). Eclipse says "The method parse(String) is undefined for the type DateTime"

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.parse(timestamp));
```

To show you the complete block which this line is about:

```
final Double value = val.getValue(); // From Outside
String timestamp = val.getTimestampIso8601();                                  

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.parse(timestamp));

Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Any ideas why this line of code doesn't work in eclipse, but in Netbeans?

Thank you

Comment: 1) check if the joda is correctly added to classpath
2) fix imports

Comment: Already checked both previously

Comment: try clean for your project

Comment: @Abu Still same error in eclipse :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using different *jars* or *maven* versions of the JodaTime library. Make sure two are the same.

I'm sorry for an answer but I can't write comments yet.